# How n (1+b) is not prime?

Tags: prime-numbers, automata

Here is the complete proof taken from [this](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-045j-automata-computability-and-complexity-spring-2011/lecture-notes/MIT6_045JS11_lec05.pdf) link

[image]

How do I convince myself that `n(1+b)` is not prime when b>=1?
Here is what I did:
if n is 3 and b is 3. Then resulting string 111 111 is prime. Is this how it should be done it in proofs? 
The way I see is this. If n(1+b) is not proved for even one set of values then I can say it is not prime. Set of values in this case was n =3 & b = 3.

Is this approach of understanding poofs is right?

Comment: [Crossposted](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/43419/how-n-1b-is-not-prime) on [cs.SE].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number $n(1+b)$ is not prime because it has 2 divisors greater than 1. These are $(b+1)$ and $n$. I believe that's what is meant here.

Comment: If there is only one state in DFA then because of `n>=p`, n can be equal to 1. What happens then? Now at least one of factor is 1. @peter.petrov

Comment: It says n is prime number. So n cannot be 1.